# Is there a way to specify the interface/class being overrode using Java's Override annotation?

Tags: java

Some classes have many interfaces that they inherit from.

I want to make it explicit in my overrided methods what interface or class my method overrides so that when I look back at my code a month from now, I don't have to do a linear search over every interface being implemented and class being extended to find which interface or class the method is being overrode for.

Situation:

```
class Foo extends Bar implements Foo1, Foo2, Bar1, Bar2
{
    public Foo(){}

    @Override
    void foo1() {}

    @Override
    void foo2() {}

    @Override
    void bar1() {}

    @Override
    void bar2() {}
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
class Foo extends Bar implements Foo1, Foo2, Bar1, Bar2
{
    public Foo(){}

    @Overrides(source="Foo2")
    void foo1() {}

    @Overrides(source="Bar1")
    void foo2() {}

    @Overrides(source="Bar2")
    void bar1() {}

    @Overrides(source="Foo1")
    void bar2() {}
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

**Solution** (thanks Nikem):

Can create a custom annotation (Overrides.java)

```
public @interface Overrides 
{
    String source() default ""; 
}
```

Comment: Can't you just mouse over the method or right-click on it to have your IDE tell you what it's overriding?

Comment: Yes but I was hoping for an IDE independant way to make it explicit.

Comment: There's nothing in the language to accomplish this.  That's the whole point: Interfaces separate signatures from implementation.  You just have to read the code.  How hard is it?

Comment: @duffymo yes but the method is being overrided for a specific interface, that is the intent. There is no issue with making it explicit, only makes the code more clear. It isn't about how "hard" it is, small things like this put together create code that discourages itself from being read.

Comment: You can always just add a comment to your source.  Note also that multiple interfaces and / or a superclass can declare methods with the same signature, so it is possible for one method to override multiple classes' / interfaces' methods.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I could but I was wondering if the language had a feature to annotate it. If not, I can just comment it but it feels ugly since I feel it should just be a part of the annotation since it's the first question people ask when reading the Override annotation(overides what?). I'm just asking if its possible or not.

Comment: For me, that is definitely not the *first* question I ask, but even if I do ask the question, I simply have the IDE give me the answer. But if you want to organize the code, you can always group the methods together and add a comment `Implementation of methods from interface X`, `Implementation of methods from interface Y`, and so on.

Comment: @Andreas it is not a sin to not use an IDE. Some people like to code in Notepad, TextPad, naked vim, or just look at a printout or github editor. Not all of them have fancy features.

Comment: @Dmitry Sure, go ahead and blindfold yourself, and you'll see that much less. It is your choice, but don't complain that you can't see anything.

Comment: Making `source()` a `String` is a bad choice. Name it `value()` and make it a `Class<?>`, and use it like `@Overrides(Foo1.class)`. That way you avoid typos, spelling errors, and staleness when interface/baseclass is renamed.

Comment: @Andreas that is a demonstration. I am checking if there is a way to subclass an annotation(seems not). As it stands you are correct, it is equivalent to a more expensive comment. That said, even as a String, I can see it being possible to check if a class with such a name exists, and since this class is unique there is no conflict in leaving it as a simple string, as the parser would notice that there is no class with such a name via reflection. For the sake of my question, I was actually asking whether this was possible, and the answer is that it is, via custom annotations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create your own annotation specifically for this purpose. Standard `@Override` annotation does not allow this.

Comment: Everyone can have his own requirements

Comment: Everyone can have their own answers, too.

Comment: @duffymo I would say: Silly. Adds no more value than simply adding a comment. ;-)

Comment: Custom annotation can be overrided to check if the class being overrided indeed contains the method, and tell you more information than a normal override would, like "you are trying to override X but X doesn't have y". whereas normal override doesn't know what you are trying to override.

Comment: @duffymo thank's mate for downvoting accepted answer.

Comment: [Answer by @caucow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37501850/5221149) mentions a better solution, which is to generate javadoc. The generated javadoc will list *all* interfaces being implemented as a "Specified by:" section.

Comment: @Andreas javadoc is a good solution but it does not make it evident in code. You still have to stop what you are doing to look at it. It's nice to know that javadoc does generate this information though, I forgot that it does.

Comment: @Nikem - your product looks interesting, even if your answer isn't.  Good luck.

Comment: @duffymo "get a better IDE" is the worst solution you can propose to anyone.

Answer (score 4):

Override annotation is just a marker and compile time check to mark that -something- is being overridden without a care for where the method being overridden comes from. As [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) said, many IDEs can show you the interface/superclass a method comes from. If you need to have an IDE independent way to accomplish this then add a comment or javadocs saying which interface it comes from.

Comment: Excellent mention of Javadoc. It will actually gives you that information **for free** as a "Specified by:" section. You don't have to do anything, other than generate the javadoc. Example: [`Integer.intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue--): ***Specified by:** `intValue` in class `Number`*. Since OP wanted information, what would be better than actual *documentation*? ;-)